# Is there any valid Python 3 code that is syntactically invalid in Python 2?

Tags: python

Just wondering, since `2to3` seems to be popular for doing Python code transformations. Will it break if I try to use it on Python 3 code? Can't find any references to this being ok or not.

Comment: Division operator has a different behavior in Python 2, so it will cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: `yield from` comes to mind.

Comment: [3to2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2) is actually a thing.  Since the language has fundamentally changed you will likely notice a difference in behavior (such as division or `yield from` as already pointed out).  Any chance on you trying it out?  As long as you've got backups/CVS, you can't hurt it that badly...

Comment: `print` itself will cause you syntax error if used without parenthesis as it is function in python 3.

Comment: `yield from` answers the question. Thanks all.